# How to check network connectivity changes for internet connection at run time with Reachability?

Tags: swift, reachability

I am using [this](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) lib for checking Reachability

And below is my sample code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let reachability = Reachability()!
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(note:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
    do{
        try reachability.startNotifier()
    }catch{
        print("could not start reachability notifier")
    }
    getUserDetail()
}
@objc func reachabilityChanged(note: Notification) {
    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability
    switch reachability.connection {
    case .wifi:
        internetConnectionView.isHidden = true
    case .cellular:
        internetConnectionView.isHidden = true
    case .none:
        internetConnectionView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

But I am not able to achieve this when i am switching wifi on and off at run time.

I don't know what I am missing.

[Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=23930915383041670449) is my sample project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced the same issue before, to resolve it you need to declare

```
let reachability = Reachability()!
```

outside `viewWillAppear` function and your code will look like:

```
let reachability = Reachability()!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(note:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
    do{
        try reachability.startNotifier()
    }catch{
        print("could not start reachability notifier")
    }
    getUserDetail()
}
```

Comment: Happy to help.. :)